# x86 assembler, strange behaviour of add and sub

Tags: assembly, masm

I have this piece of code:

```
openFileToRead:
sub sp,4
add sp,4
ret
```

then I have in my code

```
call openFileToRead
```

And now we have a problem. It all works when there is a sub before add, but when I change the sub with add like here:

```
openFileToRead:
add sp,4
sub sp,4
ret
```

all hell breaks loose. In ret he jumps to some strange location and memory. There shouldn't be any difference between those two labels, but there is. Why is that?

I compile with masm on windows xp with Intel CPU, I use 16 bit linker.

Comment: Are you sure `sp` doesn't overflow when you add to it?

Comment: Run your program through a debugger to check the value of `sp`. If it's at its highest value then it'll overflow when having 4 added to it.

Comment: No, this is not possible with my little stack, only 200 words, I watched behaviour under debug, sp moves as expected, there is only problem with value on stack, and as I stated this codes behaves in a strange fashion only if there is add and then sub.

Comment: @user1044110: What's the address the stack pointer is pointing to?

Comment: after call: 0186, after sub:0182, after add and before ret:0186

Comment: The stack must grow downwards.  Not sure what you're runtime environment looks like, but if there are any hardware interrupts then you'll pay dearly when the interrupt handler overwrites the return address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't ever have an `add` to the stack pointer before a `sub`, in the same way that you shouldn't ever have a `pop` before a `push`.

When you `add` to the stack, you're basically saying that anything at an address less than what's pointed to by the stack pointer is free memory to be used. When you `sub` from the stack is when you're essentially allocating memory. The stack pointer starts at high memory and moves towards low memory as things are pushed onto the stack.

In the comment above, Hans has a point with the interrupts. If *anything* takes control after the `add` and *uses the stack*, it'll overwrite your return address. That's because you've basically "deallocated" it by adding to the stack pointer.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that an interrupt - say a clock tick - is serviced right after your add sp,4, clobbering your return value, which at that precise moment appears to be in an unused area of the stack (below the stack pointer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it's a threading/interrupt issue - change stack, thread happens, come back and boom.  Serves you write for playing with your stack pointer like that :)

Comment: Ok, but for example when I want to pass some values to function I think that using the stack is a good way to do it, push them on stack, when in function or somewhere else move sp to previous location and pop those values, just making sure that sp is in the right position before ret.

Comment: @user1044110: never have a `pop` before a `push`, never add to the stack pointer before subtracting.